# SAPUI5 xml view error

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

I'm new at sapui5 mvc i searched everywhere but nothing seem to work for me.
I have a simple view and controller and just need a help to start with this.
I have to do this with separated files.
Here is my code

LinkGroup.view.xml

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="sap.m.sample.Link.LinkGroup"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <l:VerticalLayout
    class="marginVerticalContent"
    width="100%">
    <l:content>
      <Link
        text="Click me"
        press="handleLinkPress" />
      <Link
        text="Disabled link"
        enabled="false" />
      <Link
        text="Open SAP Homepage"
        target="_blank"
        href="http://www.sap.com" />
    </l:content>
  </l:VerticalLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

LinkGroup.controller.js

```
sap.ui.controller("sap.m.sample.Link.LinkGroup", {

    handleLinkPress: function (evt) {
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");
        sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Link was clicked!");
    }

});
```

index.aspx

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

      sap.ui.controller("LinkGroup", { });

      var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
          viewContent: jQuery('#LinkGroup').html()
      });

      oView.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({ }));

      oView.placeAt('content');

    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This throws the "Neither view name/content nor an XML node is given" error.
Every help appreciated

Comment: Maybe the line `sap.ui.controller("LinkGroup", { });` in your index.aspx is playing havoc, as you already defined a controller `sap.m.sample.Link.LinkGroup`

Comment: Thank you..I tried to remove that line..nothing changed..same error

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error comes from:

```
var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
    viewContent: jQuery('#LinkGroup').html()
});
```

It expects a DOM element with ID `LinkGroup` which is most likely not available (if your XMLView is part of the `index.html` file within `<script>` tag which has an ID `LinkGroup`, then it would work):

```
<script id="LinkGroup" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View
        controllerName="sap.m.sample.Link.LinkGroup"
        xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns="sap.m">
        <!-- etc -->
    </mvc:View>
</script>
```

However, if your XMLView is in a separate file, you could simply use this in your `index.html`:

```
var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idmain1", viewName:"sap.m.sample.Link.LinkGroup", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
view.placeAt("content");
```

Comment: Thank you Qualiture..I still get this error                                     XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/m/sample/Link/LinkGroup.view.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2834' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: Does the reference to your view contains the view object or is it undefined? Are there any 404 errors in the console?

Comment: Ah, that is because your view/controller namespace is a) not reflected in the folder structure, or b) you haven't set the default root in your index.html; `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "sap.m.sample.Link" : "./", }`

Comment: Still can't get it..it throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mvc' of undefined..this is the script in my head section                        <script id='Script1' type='text/javascript' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
        data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.ui.core, sap.m'
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "sap.m.sample.Link" : "./", }'></script>

Comment: At what line is it throwing? EDIT: there is no need for including `sap.ui.core` in your bootstrapper libs

Comment: this line:  var view = sap.ui.view({ id: "main1", viewName: "sap.m.sample.Link.LinkGroup", type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML });            and there is a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } that i dont know from where does it come

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73176/discussion-between-qualiture-and-dvita).